# Getting Display Name from PackageID

Tags: wix, wix3.6, bootstrapper, burn

Looking through the source of the Wix Standard Bootstrapper application, it appears that each package has a **DisplayName** property:

```
pPackage->sczDisplayName
```

However, the BootstrapperCore dll that is used in the WiX Setup project does not have this property. Is there any way to extract this property from the bundles in managed code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ported the `Bal` code into C#, trying to make it work exactly like the C++ code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

public class BootstrapperApplicationData
{
    public const string defaultFileName = "BootstrapperApplicationData.xml";
    public const string xmlNamespace = 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2010/BootstrapperApplicationData";

    private static DirectoryInfo defaultFolder;
    public static DirectoryInfo DefaultFolder
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultFolder == null)
            {
                defaultFolder = (new FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)).Directory;
            }
            return defaultFolder;
        }
    }

    private static FileInfo defaultFile;
    public static FileInfo DefaultFile
    {
        get
        {
            if (defaultFile == null)
            {
                defaultFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(DefaultFolder.FullName, defaultFileName));
            }
            return defaultFile;
        }
    }

    public FileInfo DataFile { get; protected set; }
    public Bundle Data { get; protected set; }

    public BootstrapperApplicationData() : this(DefaultFile) { }

    public BootstrapperApplicationData(FileInfo fiBootstrapperApplicationData)
    {
        DataFile = fiBootstrapperApplicationData;
        using (FileStream fs = DataFile.OpenRead())
        {
            Data = ParseBundleFromStream(fs);
        }
    }

    public static Bundle ParseBundleFromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        XPathDocument manifest = new XPathDocument(stream);
        XPathNavigator root = manifest.CreateNavigator();
        return ParseBundleFromXml(root);
    }

    public static Bundle ParseBundleFromXml(XPathNavigator root)
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(root.NameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("p", xmlNamespace);
        XPathNavigator bundleNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/p:BootstrapperApplicationData/p:WixBundleProperties", namespaceManager);

        if (bundleNode == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to select bundle information");
        }

        bool? perMachine = GetYesNoAttribute(bundleNode, "PerMachine");
        if (perMachine.HasValue)
        {
            bundle.PerMachine = perMachine.Value;
        }

        string name = GetAttribute(bundleNode, "DisplayName");
        if (name != null)
        {
            bundle.Name = name;
        }

        string logVariable = GetAttribute(bundleNode, "LogPathVariable");
        if (logVariable != null)
        {
            bundle.LogVariable = logVariable;
        }
        else
        {
            //wix would actually debug "Failed to select bundle information" and return with E_NOTFOUND, but I think it's a (harmless) bug
        }

        Package[] packages = ParsePackagesFromXml(root);
        bundle.Packages = packages;

        return bundle;
    }

    public static Package[] ParsePackagesFromXml(XPathNavigator root)
    {
        List<Package> packages = new List<Package>();

        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(root.NameTable);
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("p", xmlNamespace);
        XPathNodeIterator nodes = root.Select("/p:BootstrapperApplicationData/p:WixPackageProperties", namespaceManager);

        foreach (XPathNavigator node in nodes)
        {
            Package package = new Package();

            string id = GetAttribute(node, "Package");
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get package identifier for package");
            }
            package.Id = id;

            string displayName = GetAttribute(node, "DisplayName");
            if (displayName != null)
            {
                package.DisplayName = displayName;
            }

            string description = GetAttribute(node, "Description");
            if (description != null)
            {
                package.Description = description;
            }

            PackageType? packageType = GetPackageTypeAttribute(node, "PackageType");
            if (!packageType.HasValue)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get package type for package");
            }
            package.Type = packageType.Value;

            bool? permanent = GetYesNoAttribute(node, "Permanent");
            if (!permanent.HasValue)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get permanent settings for package");
            }
            package.Permanent = permanent.Value;

            bool? vital = GetYesNoAttribute(node, "Vital");
            if (!vital.HasValue)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get vital setting for package");
            }
            package.Vital = vital.Value;

            bool? displayInternalUI = GetYesNoAttribute(node, "DisplayInternalUI");
            if (!displayInternalUI.HasValue)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get DisplayInternalUI setting for package");
            }
            package.DisplayInternalUI = displayInternalUI.Value;

            string productCode = GetAttribute(node, "ProductCode");
            if (productCode != null)
            {
                package.ProductCode = productCode;
            }

            string upgradeCode = GetAttribute(node, "UpgradeCode");
            if (upgradeCode != null)
            {
                package.UpgradeCode = upgradeCode;
            }

            string version = GetAttribute(node, "Version");
            if (version != null)
            {
                package.Version = version;
            }

            packages.Add(package);
        }

        return packages.ToArray();
    }

    public static string GetAttribute(XPathNavigator node, string attributeName)
    {
        XPathNavigator attribute = node.SelectSingleNode("@" + attributeName);

        if (attribute == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return attribute.Value;
    }

    public static bool? GetYesNoAttribute(XPathNavigator node, string attributeName)
    {
        string attributeValue = GetAttribute(node, attributeName);

        if (attributeValue == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return attributeValue.Equals("yes", StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static PackageType? GetPackageTypeAttribute(XPathNavigator node, string attributeName)
    {
        string attributeValue = GetAttribute(node, attributeName);

        if (attributeValue == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (attributeValue.Equals("Exe", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return PackageType.EXE;
        }
        else if (attributeValue.Equals("Msi", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return PackageType.MSI;
        }
        else if (attributeValue.Equals("Msp", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return PackageType.MSP;
        }
        else if (attributeValue.Equals("Msu", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return PackageType.MSU;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public enum PackageType
    {
        EXE,
        MSI,
        MSP,
        MSU,
    }

    public class Package
    {
        public string Id;
        public string DisplayName;
        public string Description;
        public PackageType Type;
        public bool Permanent;
        public bool Vital;
        public bool DisplayInternalUI;

        //not available until WiX 3.9.421.0
        public string ProductCode;
        public string UpgradeCode;
        public string Version;
    }

    public class Bundle
    {
        public bool PerMachine;
        public string Name;
        public string LogVariable;
        public Package[] Packages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` file that is generated during the build process is placed next to your BA .dll. You can load that XML file to get lots of information about the bundle and packages in the bundle.

To load the `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` in native code, use the `BalManifestLoad()` method in `balutil.lib` that is provided with the WiX toolset. You can see the code in `src\ext\BalExtension\balutil\balutil.cpp`. Then you can use `BalInfoParseFromXml()` also in `balutil.lib` to parse the XML file into a bunch of handy structs. You can see the code in `src\ext\BalExtension\balutil\balinfo.cpp`.

Comment: Thanks for this info. We can query this to get the Display Name, as we already have PackageId available in different events/methods.

Comment: But don't you think, Display Name or Application Name should be available just like PackageId, ProductCode etc.?

Comment: We keep the interface between the engine and BootstrapperApplication as minimal as possible since that defines a contract that breaks anytime we add/remove/change it. The application data manifest is not an interface contract so we can grow as necessary. Said another way the interface has the **necessary** data to find all the other data.