# Managed WiX Bootstrapper packages

Tags: wix

I have chained multiple Msi/exec packages in my Bundle.wxs. In my managed Bootstrapper code, I would like to get the parameters (such as DisplayName, Vital, etc) of the current package that is being executed.
Right now, I have only found events that provide the packageID. Can I use this to somehow access other properties of the package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. A file called `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` is created during the build process and included with your Bootstrapper Application. The `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` has lots of information about the bundle and packages included in your `Bundle` `Chain`, including the `DisplayName` and sizes and vital.

You'll find the `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` right next to your .dll. In managed code you can get it using the following code:

```
 string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 string dataXmlPath = Path.Combine(folder, "BootstrapperApplicationData.xml");
```

In native code, it is easier to use the helper functions provided in the `balutil.lib`. Namely `BalManifestLoad()` then `BalInfoParseFromXml()` to parse the XML file into a bunch of handy structs. You can see the code in src\ext\BalExtension\balutil\balinfo.cpp.

Finally, the `BootstrapperApplicationData.xml` can be extended by using `CustomTable` elements and setting the `BootstrapperAppplicationData='yes'` attribute.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you once again.

Comment: I gave C# code to parse the XML in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17548224/628981).