# How to read out MSI package versions from Burn bootstrapper installer with C#?

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper, burn

We are using the default bootstrapper application included with burn.

We try to somehow include the versions of the MSI-packages in a text field or attribute during build and read out the information of the included packages via C# without installing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managed WiX Bootstrapper packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412193/managed-wix-bootstrapper-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpack WIX Burn bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889383/unpack-wix-burn-bundle)

Comment: The BootstrapperApplicationData.xml mentioned in the other question's answer is extractable with dark.exe (or you can use another exe extractor like 7-zip but that's harder because the filenames are the internal ones.)

Comment: We could not achieve it as asked but we took the workaround to use  something similar to a self-extracting executable which just extracts the bootstrapper content.