# Add Metadata/Resources to Bootstrapper using WiX

Tags: wix

I use Wix to bootstrap multiple MSIs. I would like to add some meta data to the generated exe file. But I do not want to use the description field, etc.
Is there a way to include a resource (like a string table) while (or after) compilation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managed WiX Bootstrapper packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412193/managed-wix-bootstrapper-packages)

Comment: Nope. The Bootstrapper data is available at runtime only. I need to access it without running the process.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. You'll have to run some code to extract anything from the file so the answer would depend on that process. dark.exe can get you the bootstrapper's internal files.